# gsub() on all values in a dataframe with multiple replacements

Tags: r, gsub

I have a large data frame with strings indicating land use over time (yearly from 1972-2020) at thousands of locations (Land_Use).  There are 23 land use strings (defined as factors in my data frame) and I want to simplify these down into 3.  I have these simplifications matched up in another dataframe (Simple), which I am currently not using in the code but I feel like I could to make it more efficient some how.

For example I want to replace all the land use strings that are "lake", "ocean", "river", "pond" with a single string called "water".  All the land use strings that say "native forest", "exotic forest",... with a single string called "forest".  And all the land use strings that say "pig farming", "exotic grassland", "diary farming", ... with a single string call "pasture"

I have made various attempts at doing this using gsub and lapply but I can't get it to work.

How would I do this and is there an efficient way to do this on the entire dataframe at once or do I need to do it column by column, and land use by land use?

```
Land_Use <- read.csv("Data\\Land_Use.csv")
Simple <- read.csv("Data\\Land_Use_simplified_classes.csv")

Land_Use <- gsub('native forest','forest.',Land_Use$1972)  # the replacement works but my dataframe become a vector containing only data from 1972

lapply(Land_Use, function(y) gsub("native forest", "forest", y))  # something very weird happened - I think it has converted to a list, not sure if the replacement worked
```

Comment: You need to assign: `Land_Use[] <- lapply(...)`. Also, consider setting `fixed = TRUE` within `gsub`.

Comment: It sounds like you just want to join your mapping on to your data. Does `Simple` represent the mapping from the 23 different values down to the 3? And you have 49 yearly columns that all need the same mapping applied?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`lapply` returns a list you can assign it to dataframe with `[]` to keep the dimensions.

```
Land_Use[] <- lapply(Land_Use, function(y) gsub("native forest", "forest", y))
```

Here `gsub` will be applied to all the column in the dataframe.

For one column you need to assign the output back to column again instead of dataframe.

```
Land_Use$`1972` <- gsub('native forest','forest.',Land_Use$`1972`)
```

---

If you want to change multiple values into one value you may want to look at `fct_collapse` function from `forcats`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(forcats)

Land_Use %>%
  mutate(across(.fns = ~fct_collapse(.x, 'Forest' = c('native forest', 'exotic forest'), 
                             'water' = c('lake', 'river', 'ocean', 'pond')))) -> Land_Use

Land_Use
```

Comment: Thank you!  I used fct_collapse from forcats and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there are better ways but this works and is simple. For each set of replacements you can run a separate `sub` operation (`gsub` is not required as you have just one match per value). For each replacement set you can use either an alternation pattern, as for the items replaced by `water`, or use regularities in the strings, such as the recurrence of `forest` in the set you want to replace with `forest`, and the recurrence of either `grassland` or `farming` in the set of values you want to replace with `pasture`:

```
df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) sub("\\b(lake|ocean|river|pond)\\b", "water", x))
df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) sub(".*(forest)", "\\1", x)) # also: sub(".*(forest)", "forest", x)
df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) sub(".*(farming|grassland)", "pasture", x))
```

Result:

```
df
        x      y       z
1   water forest pasture
2   water forest pasture
3   water forest pasture
4   water forest pasture
5  forest  water  forest
6  forest  water   water
7 pasture  water   water
```

Data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  x = c("lake", "ocean", "river", "pond","native forest", "exotic forest", "diary farming"),
  y = c("native forest", "exotic forest", "native forest", "exotic forest","lake", "ocean", "river"),
  z = c("pig farming", "exotic grassland", "diary farming", "exotic grassland","exotic forest","lake", "ocean")
)
```